# ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run the powershell script below to identify the USB or SCSI interfacetype connected to the computer, the script works just fine if I don't use the `IF` and `-Or` operators

```
if(($diskdrive = (gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq 'USB'})) -Or ($diskdrive =(gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq 'SCSI'}))){
$letters = $diskdrive | %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF 
{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE

AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |  %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS

OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass =

Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} | %{$_.Deviceid}
setx OSDUSBDrive $letters /M 
Write-Output $diskdrive, $letters}
Start-Sleep -s 5


    if (-not ("Win32.NativeMethods" -as [Type]))
    {
        # import sendmessagetimeout from win32
    Add-Type -Namespace Win32 -Name NativeMethods -MemberDefinition @"
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
        IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, string lParam,
        uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, out UIntPtr lpdwResult);
"@
    }

    $HWND_BROADCAST = [IntPtr] 0xffff;
    $WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1a;
    $result = [UIntPtr]::Zero

    # notify all windows of environment block change
    [Win32.Nativemethods]::SendMessageTimeout($HWND_BROADCAST, $WM_SETTINGCHANGE, [UIntPtr]::Zero, "Environment", 2, 5000, [ref] $result);

Start-Sleep -s 5
```

> ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2'
>   time(s). C:\temp\AddOSDUSBDrive_NEW.ps1:10 : 1
>   + setx OSDUSBDrive $letters /M
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Erreurÿ: Syntax...plus de 2 fois.:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError   Entrez "SETX /?" pour afficher la syntaxe.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setx OSDUSBDrive "$letters" /M`

Applied [`SETX.exe` syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) pattern

> ```
> SETX [/s Computer [Credentials]] Variable Value [/m]
>                                           ↑↑↑↑↑
> ```

could be wrong if `$letters` contains more *letters* e.g. `F:`, `G:`, `H:`

```
 setx OSDUSBDrive $letters /M
 #                ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑        this evaluates to
 setx OSDUSBDrive F: G: H: /M
 #                ↑↑ ↑↑ ↑↑        three space-separated values (WRONG)
```

Adjusted (see [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)):

```
 setx OSDUSBDrive "$letters" /M
 #                ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑       this evaluates to
 setx OSDUSBDrive "F: G: H:" /M
 #                 ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑        one string value (quotes = escape characters)
```

**Moreover**, I'd adjust the first `IF` as follows:

```
if ( $diskdrive = ( Get-WmiObject win32_diskdrive | 
        Where-Object { $_.interfacetype -in ('USB','SCSI') } ) ) {
```

**Explanation**: `-or` operator means logical OR: *`TRUE` when either* i.e. if first operand evaluates to `TRUE`, then other operands are never evaluated.

For instance, run

```
Remove-Variable a, b -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ( ($a = 1) -or ($b = 3) ) { Write-host "a=$a b=$b" }
```

> The variable '$b' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.

```
if ( ($a = $null) -or ($b = 3) ) { Write-host "a=$a b=$b" }
```

> a= b=3

Comment: That works when I run it manually, however I get this error when it's called from SCCM
The argument 'AddOSDUSBDrive _NEW.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I actually added  this as you suggested :

> if ( $diskdrive = ( Get-WmiObject win32_diskdrive | 
>           Where-Object { $_.interfacetype -in ('USB','SCSI') } ) ) {

the script works fine when I run it manually, however I get the error below when it's called from SCCM

> You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-'
>   operator. TaskSequencePSHost  3/6/2018 4:36:37 PM 0 (0x0000) At
>   D:\SMS\PKG\SE1001B5\AddOSDUSBDrive_NEW.ps1:2 char:42
>   +         Where-Object { $_.interfacetype - <<<< in ('USB','SCSI') } ) ){ TaskSequencePSHost  3/6/2018 4:36:37 PM 0 (0x0000) ParserError: (:)
>   [], ParseException    TaskSequencePSHost  3/6/2018 4:36:37 PM 0 (0x0000)
>   TSHOST: Script completed with return code
>   0 TaskSequencePSHost  3/6/2018 4:36:37 PM 0 (0x0000)